# Android app crashes cause of spinner

Tags: android

When I open this page the app unexpectly stops it has no issues without the spinner options but when I add them the app crashes...

logcat text http://pastebin.com/umKP8iD0

```
    package com.calc;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Adapter;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;
    import android.view.View;


    public class setup extends Activity
    {

        TextView start, end;
        TimePicker startTime, endTime;
        Spinner day;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            String dayText[] = new String[6];
            start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            startTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
            endTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
            day = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            dayText[0] = "Sunday";
            dayText[1] = "Monday";
            dayText[2] = "Tuesday";
            dayText[3] = "Wednesday";
            dayText[4] = "Thursday";
            dayText[5] = "Friday";
            dayText[6] = "Saturday";
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dayText);
            day.setAdapter(adapter);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.enterpage);
        }
    }
```

Im wondering if it is because the spinner am I creating it wrong?

Comment: Can you post your LogCat data? Also, try putting `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` at the very beginning of the method.

Comment: added the logcat at the beginning of the post

Comment: ]Definitely the array issue I mention in my edit, oh, welcome to SO.  If you haven't seen it yet you might want to check out this [link]( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setContentView`before you can get view ids...

If you try and get ids before you set a view they will return null and then you will get NPE issues.

Move that so it's first and your app should work.

EDIT

You also are not setting enough slots in your array.  you call for 6 slots and try to put seven items into it.  Try this:

```
String daytext[] = new String[7];
```

Comment: Does your `R.layout.enterpage`contain those Id's you are trying to find?  As I said, you have to set the content view first, and it must contain the id's you are trying to access.  Post your logcat so we cn pinpoint the problem.